# IPython 0.12 Error

Tags: ipython

I am using IPython 0.12 for a master-slave style HPC task. I just switch from 0.10.1 to 0.12. I do not change much about my code. But the ipcontroller and client program output the following message:

```
E: Unhandled error on recv: 11/Resource temporarily unavailable
E: Unhandled error on send: 11/Resource temporarily unavailable
E: Unhandled error on recv: 11/Resource temporarily unavailable
E: Unhandled error on send: 11/Resource temporarily unavailable
E: Unhandled error on recv: 11/Resource temporarily unavailable
E: Unhandled error on send: 11/Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The processes are still running. I even do not know where are the bugs? How can I trace the bugs? Is that just a warning?

Comment: What version of libzmq do you have? (`import zmq; print zmq.zmq_version()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in libzmq-2.1.10, and should go away if you update to the current release (currently 2.1.11).

ref: http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2011-October/013749.html